# i18n dart library for translation won't run

Tags: internationalization, dart, angular

Hello i run the command

```
pub run intl:extract_to_arb --output-dir=target/directory
```

But i take this error message:

```
Package "intl" is not an immediate dependency.
Cannot run executables in transitive dependencies.
```

i follow this site https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/intl/0.11.9/index.html and i use api 1.15.1

There is another way to do that?

Comment: The error message says that you didn't add `intl` to your dependencies in `pubspec.yaml`. Did you?

Comment: okay. it  solve my problem. but the output file must be created before launch this command?i take this:  FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '--output-dir=/Volumes/Case Sensitive Part/Projects/text.dart' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: Is it only the file `text.dart` that doesn't exist or does also the `/Volumes/Case Sensitive Part/Projects/` directory not exist? I haven't used message extraction myself yet. Try a relative directory instead of an absolute one. I assume the output should be created in the same project? You also need to wrap the path in quotes if it contains a space.

Comment: i try but it doesn't work. Can you post me an example?

Comment: As mentioned I haven't used this feature myself. "doesn't work" is not enough information to be able to provide any support. What exactly have you tried and what error message to you get?

Comment: can you write an example of your translation file? for the feature i do that: 1) create file under web/resources/translations.dart. 2) launch this command pub run intl:extract_to_arb --output-dir="resources/translations.dart" the compiler says again FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '--output-dir=resources/translations.dart' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Comment: It sounds like you're giving it a file as the output directory. It should be a directory. What happens if you just leave off the output directory and just run it in that directory instead?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have a solution:

```
pub run intl:extract_to_arb --output-dir="/Volumes/Case Sensitive Part/Projects/MyProjectFolder/" web/dart/**/*.dart
```

This generate a file intl_messages.arb (a Json for the translator).
From the translator you can receive some file like this

- intl_messages_fr.arb
- intl_messages_de.arb
- intl_messages_{locale}.arb to generalize.

After this:

```
  pub run intl:generate_from_arb --generated-file-prefix=notneeded web/dart/**/*.dart  ./intl_messages_fr.arb ./intl_messages_de.arb ./intl_messages_{locale}.arb
```

This generate a class dart named: "messages_all.dart" and dart class named "messages_messages_de.dart", "messages_messages_fr.dart", "messages_messages_{locale}.dart".

Only one problem left. I receive some info from last command generate_from_arb:

No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_messages_it, assuming 'messages_it' based on the file name.
No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_messages_de, assuming 'messages_de' based on the file name.

I thing that i should put this tag @@locale (@@it) inside the translation arb files.